# Bluetooth BLE Battery Level - C#

Tags: c#, arrays, windows, visual-studio, bluetooth

I have an specific issue about the Bluetooth BLE API on Windows 10.
At the moment I'm programming a tool on C# (Visual Studio) which connects itself to a given BLE - Device. Currently the connection works perfect and I can read out the **ServiceUUIDs** and the **CharacterUUIDs**.

The main Problem is after I try to read the value of the Character its always returns me 00. I heard that implementing a notification will change that and I followed these [instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/gatt-client)  but they didn't help me.

(Here are the Specifications from [bluetooth.com](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/viewer?attributeXmlFile=org.bluetooth.characteristic.battery_level.xml):)

My Code:

```
 //connect to BluetoothDevice
        var device = await BluetoothLEDevice.FromIdAsync(address);

        //get UUID of Services
        var services = await device.GetGattServicesAsync();
        if (services != null)
        {
            foreach (var servicesID in services.Services)
            {

                //if there is a service thats same like the Battery Service
                if (servicesID.Uuid.ToString() == BluetoothBLE.Constants.BATTERY_SERVICE)
                {
                    //updateServiceList is like a console logging in my tool
                    updateServiceList($"Service: {servicesID.Uuid}");

                    var characteristics = await servicesID.GetCharacteristicsAsync();
                    foreach (var character in characteristics.Characteristics)
                    {
                        if (Constants.BATTERY_LEVEL == character.Uuid.ToString())
                        {

                            updateServiceList("C - UUID: "+ character.Uuid.ToString());
                            GattReadResult result = await character.ReadValueAsync();
                            if (result.Status == GattCommunicationStatus.Success)
                            {
                               var reader = DataReader.FromBuffer(result.Value);
                               byte[] input = new byte[reader.UnconsumedBufferLength];
                               reader.ReadBytes(input);
                               System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(input));

                            }

                        }
                        }

                }
```

After Running my Code, the system logs  `00`. The characterUUID for battery level (0x2A19, from https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/viewer?attributeXmlFile=org.bluetooth.characteristic.battery_level.xml) was read successfully but the value is strange..

Comment: If you use Windows 10 1803 and have your device paired then you must unpair it and connect without pairing. The other problem can be in ReadValueAsync() function, try to call it as ReadValueAsync(BluetoothCacheMode.Uncached);

Comment: First thank you for answering. BluetoothCacheMode.Uncached didnt work. How can i get an instance of a BluetoothLEDevice without pairing it?

Comment: It says for both Methods(FromIdAsync, FromBluetoothAddressAsync), which return a BLE Device : "gets an instance of BleDevice and starts a connection".

Comment: FromBluetoothAddressAsync (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.bluetooth.bluetoothledevice.frombluetoothaddressasync#Windows_Devices_Bluetooth_BluetoothLEDevice_FromBluetoothAddressAsync_System_UInt64_). You can test if your device works using this application: http://www.btframework.com/GattClient.zip There is compiled exe in Release folder (and its source code). Unpair device first.

Comment: I tried the GattClient.zip. I saw its your Code. The Tool works fine for my Device. The Thing is im not allowed to use other Libaries except that one from windows, its a student project. I will message you if FromBluetoothAddressAsync worked.

Comment: That was just to detect where the problem is. In fact 1803 has bug that does not actualy read values from device it is paired.

Comment: @MikePetrichenko It seems like if it works. I changed my code from:

Comment: var device = await BluetoothLEDivce.FromIdAsync => to : var device = await BluetoothLEDivce.FromBluetoothAdress(address) as you told me to do. Thank you very much.

Comment: The only thing in need to do now, is when the value changes in background that my tool displays that also. So i will try to work with Notification of the character. Are you familiar with it , maybe i will have some issues. Thank you again. Very friendly and helpful man.

Comment: Yes, of course. You have to use notifications. Also do not forget to write Client Configuration Descriptor of the required characteristic. Otherwise you'll not get notifications.

Comment: @MikePetrichenko It seems like it works for notification. Thanks for the advice with the configuration descriptor. Thank you sir for your help. I will text you (if im allowed) if i need something else for bluetooth BLE. Cause Batterly Level wont be the only service i will need. Thank you. Greetings.

Comment: You are very welcome. Sure, ask if need help.

Comment: Hello @MikePetrichenko its me again... So I tried with the same way to get the data of a HeartMeasurement- Character. So after i get the specific service and character of the bluetoothdevice. He doesnt log me anymore the value of the character:  https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/viewer?attributeXmlFile=org.bluetooth.characteristic.heart_rate_measurement.xml

Comment: The code is the same like above, just the if clauses are different. So instead of checking if the service uuid and character uuid is from battery service and character I check if the service and character are for heartmeasurement.

Comment: Is GattClient demo able to read value?

Comment: No it doesnt work on GattClient. If i press "Get Value" nothing is shown. I tried after it with battery level and it worked.

Comment: Then your device does not report it or characteristic is not readable but notifiable instead. So you probably need to subscribe to its notifications.

Comment: One short thing i discovered: after the check if the character contains the uuid of the heart measurement (0x2A37) i declare the method: GattReadResult result = await character.ReadValueAsync(); After that one I declare a if clause: if (result.Status == GattCommunicationStatus.Success) { // here i read the character data into the byte array}.   But i guess here is the problem. My tool doesnt even get into this forloop after i tried just to log something to console inside the if clause. With battery character it works...

Comment: As I wrote above the characteristic you are trying to read is not readable (https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/viewer?attributeXmlFile=org.bluetooth.service.heart_rate.xml) it is notifiable.

Comment: if have this right now: GattCommuicationStatus status = await character.WriteClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorAsync(GattDescriptor.Notify); if(status == GattCommunicationStatus.Succes){ cahracter.ValueChanged += Character_ValueChanged; and then the  method "Character_ValueChanged"  where i get the value from its paramter  : args.CharacteristicValue. Wht do you think about it ? I cant test it cause im at work...

Comment: @MikePetrichenko okay i tested it now. It seems to work now. But the console logs me weird formats : 01-00-00 , 11-00-00-BE-2E , 01-00-00. I guess i have to check the specifications. Any guesses what the first 2 numbers (Bytes) could stand for?

Comment: Yesm you did all absolutely correct. Format described there: https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/viewer?attributeXmlFile=org.bluetooth.characteristic.heart_rate_measurement.xml

Comment: Thank you. It works everything fine now. The first 2 numbers stand for the format. So 01 is uint8. The 3rd and the 4rd number are for the real value. Depending on which format the value is given i just need to convert them into decimalsystem. Thank you again Sir and have a nice week. Youre my hero haha :)

Comment: @MikePetrichenko hello Mr. Petrichenko. I have another question concerning bluetooth. If i measure the heart rate i get different strructures of bytes.

Comment: Sometime i get bytes like these: : "11-4A-00-3B-03"; from my bluetooth device. Just from converting all these bytes into decimal i suggested that the 2nd bytes (so "4A") stands for the heart rate. The thing is that i want also the hear rate variabitly. But i really dont know what part of the bytes it is. I tried to understand the advice from blueetoth.org about the format of the bytestructure but i couldnt manage to understand that.
 Thats a other print of the bluetooth device a bit later "11-4B-00-4C-03-2B-03".

Comment: another log:
11-4F-00-EE-02-F7-02 
11-43-00-49-03-1E-03
11-43-00-AC-03-6C-03
11-49-00-03-03
11-40-00-33-02-17-05

Comment: 11 - One or more RR-Interval values are present. (С4) + Heart Rate Value Format is set to UINT16. Units: beats per minute (bpm) (С2); 004А (uint16) - heat rate value; next RR intervals. Refer to format description.

Comment: okay understood. Thank you