# Read property from device manager?

Tags: c#, wpf

There is some way to read property from device manager?

I need read the battery status of surface dial without pair to the surface dial from my desktop C# WPF app.

[Link to screen capture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNiXZ.png)

Comment: Do you really mean the device isn't paired?  It wouldn't be in device manager.

Answer (score 0):

You can play arround with WMI queries. Here is a little example:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string query = @"SELECT * FROM Win32_PnPEntity";

        var moSearch = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query);
        var moCollection = moSearch.Get();

        foreach (ManagementObject mo in moCollection)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(mo.Path.ToString());
            foreach (var item in mo.Properties)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{item.Name}: {item.Value}");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Remember to add `System.Management` reference to the project.

Look on the Device Manager for the exact `DeviceId` or `DevicePath` in order to put a `WHERE` statement in your query.

For more info about classes and queries in WMI here is the official documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/cimwin32prov/computer-system-hardware-classes

Comment: Hello Guido, thanks for your reply.

Device instance path:  BTHLE\DEV_BC83851FE704\7&222CF7DF&0&BC83851FE704

HardwareID :  BTHLE\Dev_bc83851fe704


I not understand how use this info in the query

Comment: That code is just example... Your shuold look for other classes to query on the link I provided and filter by your DeviceId. Anyways, I just saw that you want to get battery level of Bluetooth device, maybe this question helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50833966/bluetooth-ble-battery-level-c-sharp

Answer (score 0):

This is the result running your example, no idea how query for "Bluetooth LE battery level"

```
\\DESKTOP-54P9Q3C\root\cimv2:Win32_PnPEntity.DeviceID="BTHLE\\DEV_BC83851FE704\\7&222CF7DF&0&BC83851FE704"
 Availability:
 Caption: Surface Dial
 ClassGuid: {e0cbf06c-cd8b-4647-bb8a-263b43f0f974}
 CompatibleID: System.String[]
 ConfigManagerErrorCode: 0
 ConfigManagerUserConfig: False
 CreationClassName: Win32_PnPEntity
 Description: Bluetooth LE Device
 DeviceID: BTHLE\DEV_BC83851FE704\7&222CF7DF&0&BC83851FE704
 ErrorCleared:
 ErrorDescription:
 HardwareID: System.String[]
 InstallDate:
 LastErrorCode:
 Manufacturer: Microsoft
 Name: Surface Dial
 PNPClass: Bluetooth
 PNPDeviceID: BTHLE\DEV_BC83851FE704\7&222CF7DF&0&BC83851FE704
 PowerManagementCapabilities:
 PowerManagementSupported:
 Present: True
 Service: BthLEEnum
 Status: OK
 StatusInfo:
 SystemCreationClassName: Win32_ComputerSystem
 SystemName: DESKTOP-54P9Q3C
```

Comment: No property "Bluetooth LE battery level"